# How do you show whether the given is a Vector Space over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm stuck on a HW problem for my Linear Algebra class.

The problem is the following:

If the set is a vector space over $\mathbb R$, write *true* and explain why each of the following ten properties hold. If the set is not a vector space over $\mathbb R$, write *false* and identify all of the properties I-X which do not hold.

> (a) $\{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^2 \:|\: 3x + 2y = 0 \}$ over $\mathbb R$ with the usual definitions of vector addition and scalar multiplication in $\mathbb R^2$

Now, I know what Vector Space over $\mathbb R$ is. I understand the question. There are 10 conditions that I must prove in order to prove that the given is a Vector Space over $\mathbb R$.

I just don't know where to begin. I understand that if for every $x,y$ in $V$, if $x+y$ exists in $V$, then one of the ten conditions is satisfied. How do I approach this with $3x + 2y = 0$?

A better question is what the statement $\{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^2 \:|\: 3x + 2y = 0 \}$ means. I understand it's all the $x$ and $y$ pairs which satisfy $3x + 2y = 0$, but am I supposed to break the $\mathbb R$ set in all of the possible combinations? For instance, $x = -2$, and $y = 3$ satisfies the function, but $x = 1$, $y = 1$ doesn't. So I certainly can't say that for every $x,y$ in $V$, $3x + 2y$ is in $V$.

I don't know where to begin proving. If I can only get a start somewhere, I would be able to do handle these problems well as I have a general knowledge of *what* to do, just not *how* to begin.

Thanks

Edit 1: Updated the question so it's easy to understand what it is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an element of this set, the element satisfies two conditions. The first is that it must be an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the second is that the components of this vector must satisfy
$$ ax + by = 0 $$
However these two conditions can be rephrased into something clearer. If we were to solve $y$, so the second component of the vector, from the above equation we would find that
$$y = - \frac{a}{b}x$$
So the first condition we stated, namely that the element must be in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is too broad, as there is a fixed condition for what the second component of the vector can be! From these observations we can show the following equality
$$ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ax + by = 0\} = \{ (x, -\frac{a}{b}x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
As can be seen the second component of the vector is tied to the first component by the relation we derived above. Now the axioms we are interested in showing are considerably easier!

Using the above definition of the set I'll prove that the set is closed under addition. Consider any two elements of this set. The element will be of the form
$$ (v, - \frac{3}{2}v), \ (t,  - \frac{3}{2}t)$$
for some arbitrary $v,t \in \mathbb{R}$. Now consider the sum of these two elements
$$ (v, - \frac{3}{2}v) + (t,  - \frac{3}{2}t) = (v + t, -\frac{3}{2}(v + t))$$
Well $v + t \in \mathbb{R}$ so if we denote $u = v + t$ then the sum of these two vectors gives us a vector
$$ (u, - \frac{3}{2}u)$$
and if you look at the definition of the set above, this element must belong to the set!

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I can take it from here. Thank you so much for explaining it out. I realize now that I did not understand the definition properly. I went wrong when in my notes, the professor mentioned the functions in terms of x and then continued to name the elements as x, y as well. The way you mention it, with v, t being elements cleared up my confusion. Thanks once again.

Comment: Anytime! Note in the future that when you are given equation of the form $ax + by + cz + ... = 0$ the usually imply some sort of constraint to the system, in this case the constraint makes the set we are looking at to be a graph on $\mathbb{R}^2$! These problems are usually solved by rewriting the set to a more approachable and computationally feasible set!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can write your set as the vector family
$$(t,-1.5t),\, t\in\Bbb R$$
What can you say about it?

Comment: That for any t in R, -1.5t will be it's pair?

Comment: @Vim  As the OP is struggling even with definition so I don't think its a "good" hint for OP.Regards,

Comment: @Harshil yes it is. The point is, you can verify the ten axioms for such a vector family (as a set) quite easily.